# Catalan/Motzkin numbers, which one is the greatest?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $C_n$ be the Catalan numbers (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), and $M_n$ be the Motzkin numbers (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number).

The Catalan numbers $C_n$ count the number of Dyck paths of length $n$ while $M_n$ is the number of Motzkin paths of length $n$. Since a Dyck path is a particular Motzkin path, we deduce that $M_n\geq C_n$.

But now, if I look at the asymptotic for $C_n$ and $M_n$, one has :

$C_n \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi}n^{3/2}}$ and $M_n\sim \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}3^{n+1}n^{-\frac{3}{2}}.$ So that $C_n \gg M_n$.

> How come this is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes from Wikipedia:

> The Motzkin number for n is also the number of positive integer sequences n−1 long...

and

> Cn is the number of Dyck words of length 2n...

So basically you should compare $C_n$ to $M_{2(n+1)}$.

edit: Or maybe $M_{2n}$, you should check the exact number for yourself, but it should be around twice as much.